# Sending Requests in Python Returns None When Trying to Scrape a Specific Web page

Tags: python, html, python-requests

```
shoe = input('Shoe name: ')

URL = 'https://stockx.com/search?s='+shoe

page = requests.get(URL, headers= headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

time.sleep(2) #this was to ensure the webpage was having enough time to load so that it wouldn't try to scrape a prematurely loaded website. 

test = soup.find(class_ = 'BrowseSearchDescription__SearchConfirmation-sc-1mt8qyd-1 dcjzxm')

print(test) #returns none
print(URL) #prings the URL (which is the correct URL of the website I'm attempting to scrape)
```

I understand that I could easily do this with Selenium, however, it is very inefficient as it loads up the chrome tab and navigates to the web page. I'm trying to make this efficient, and my original "prototype" did use Selenium however it was always detected as a bot and my whole code was stopped by captchas. Am I doing something wrong that is causing the code to return 'None' or is that specific webpage unscrape-able.  If you need, the specific URL is https://stockx.com/search?s=yeezy

Comment: can you provide headers if not an security issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and here is the result.

**Code**

```
shoe = 'yeezy'
URL = 'https://stockx.com/search?s='+shoe
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

And when I see what's inside the `soup`, here is the result.

**Result**

```
..
..

<div id="px-captcha">
</div>
<p> Access to this page has been denied because 
    we believe you are using automation tools to browse the website.</p>

..
..
```

Yes I guess the developers didn't want the website being **scraped**.